# Copy data from closed workbook to another open workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I know this has probably been asked before but I was wondering if it was possible to copy data from another 'closed' workbook to my current open workbook. If tried to look up some things and everywhere says it is not possible... I know it's a bit of an open ended question.

Comment: Open then close it? Set `screenupdating` to false.

Comment: No, I was trying to do it without opening the workbook at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, this takes me back a few years. I believe this was done by Ron years ago (explained on a different platform). But there are two ways to do it. One method I forgot and gets the cells one by one and the other is the ADO method posted below. First there are two example subs (one method to bring headers and the other to not) and then followed by the main ADO sub.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData_ExampleV1()
' It will copy the Header row also (the last two arguments are True)
' Change the last argument to False if you not want to copy the header row
    GetData ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xlsx", "Sheet1", _
            "A1:C5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), True, True
End Sub


Sub GetData_ExampleC2()
' It will not copy the Header row (the last two arguments are True, False)
' Change the last argument to True if you also want to copy the header row
    GetData ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xlsx", "Sheet1", _
            "A1:C5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), True, False
End Sub
```

This is the ADO (function) you call to do it.

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    If Header = False Then
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    Else
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If
    End If

    If SourceSheet = "" Then
        ' workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

    On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        If Header = False Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
            If UseHeaderRow Then
                For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                    TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                    rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
                Next lCount
                TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            Else
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            End If
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```